# How balanced is this for a cursed item? part 2

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew-review, homebrew, curses

[Part 1](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/206941/38834)

---

### Emblem of the ever lasting plague

#### Wondrous item, legendary (requires attunement)

As an action, you can summon 4 (8 at lvl 9, 12 at lvl 13 or 16 at lvl 17) [swarm of insects](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17029-swarm-of-insects). You can use their action to make them fuse with your armor (losing all other abilities), providing you 5 temporary hit points per swarm.

Controlling the swarm does require concentration and the magic will last for 1 hour.

Each time you summon the swarm you will have to make a constitution check (12), or take 1 additional exhaustion.

**Curse**. This emblem is cursed, and can't be taken off by regular means. Upon attuning to this item, you gain [one level of exhaustion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/appendix-a-conditions#Exhaustion) that cannot be healed until this item is unequipped.

Comment: yeah sorry bout that i'm super dyslectic so i noticed to late, tried to fix them in the text below, maybe i should remove the image to make the post better

Comment: I cleaned up the description a bit, added links, etc. It should still read the same, but feel free to edit if there is something incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

This is missing some important details about the item's function.

1. How often can you use this summoning action? Right now there's no clear limitation. Normally you'd specify "it regains the ability to do this at dawn" or some such thing, or else give it charges and specify how many charges it regains at dawn (or other time of day). I'm *assuming* you don't mean this to just be at will because summoning infinite monsters is just broken. If the Exhaustion is meant to be the only limiting factor... well, I have issues with exhaustion as a risk/reward element.
2. What happens if the controller loses concentration?  Do the insects disappear, or go wild, or what?
3. What's the geometry of the "gain temporary hit points" ability?  Can that happen from anywhere, no matter how far away the insect swarm is, or does the swarm (as I assume) need to move to your physical location and surround you, then merge?
4. The general rule for temporary hit points is that gaining a new amount of temporary HP replaces any existing temporary HP you have (if the new amount is greater), so unless you give it a special rule to the contrary, sucking up swarms one at a time (which is what must happen if it's something each swarm does individually on its own turn) would just keep applying 5 temporary HP that don't stack, leaving you with 5 temporary HP.

I might recommend that you make the merge have a range and make it an action (or bonus action) of the person wearing the item, like "As an action, you draw in all insect swarms within 30 feet of you and fuse them to your armor, destroying the swarms and granting you 5 temporary hit points per swarm fused." But I'm not sure that's how you're intending this to work.

Comment: I did indeed intended something like that that they merge, I didn't know if it should take an action of the pc or the swarm (i look at conjure animals as base)


2. they disperse into the wild, how that plays out is up to my dm's discression but I wanted to give him something he could play with

1. instead of once or twice a day, i wanted to make added amounts of exhaustion the factor that prevents the user from spamming this mindlessly, but maybe I should higher the save then?

Comment: @LaurensWolf here is a suggestion regarding the exhaustion issue : make the first use of the ability "free" once per long rest, and make additional uses give exhaustion, either guaranteed or with a much higher skill check. As of now, a CON check of 12 is fairly easy to deal with for most characters, so there isn't really a reason not to use the ability.

Comment: ok I will do that! yeah first one seems free and after that guarantee seems good!
is the item ready to give to my dm? (I'm not the dm but i am the most experienced player so i need to make all this kind of stuff for him)
@matthieu wanted to thank you for all your help these 3 days with my posts!

Comment: I'm not sure Exhaustion really works as a limitation. One level of exhaustion is pretty bad, and two is crippling for any character, and it's pretty hard to get rid of. To me "roll or gain exhaustion" just means I'll never EVER use the item, and "one is free after that exhaustion" just reads the same as "once per day" to me. It's fine if you want to do it, but at least from my perspective, exhaustion is too big a risk for a relatively minor reward so it's a lot of text to do nothing more complicated than the standard "at dawn" recharge.

Comment: Do you maybe have an alternative balanced cost then for casting the spell?

Comment: Once per day or charges.

Comment: ooh yeah i will do that! something likes uses 1 charge, you can have max 3-4 charges and you gain 1 charge every dawn?

Comment: So items normally don't take character level into account, the item just is what it is. I would probably recommend you can spend an action and one charge to summon two swarms, and it has 4 charges regaining 1 per day (might recommend recharging at midnight, for the flavor). As an action without spending a charge, you can destroy nearby swarms to turn them into armor. I wouldn't put a level-growth thing on there (and quite frankly more than 4 swarms is *way too many* to manage at the table anyway).

Comment: Sounds perfect!!!